# SQLite - Joining 2 tables excluding certain rows based on a partial string match

Tags: sqlite, sum, left-join, where-clause, sql-like

Imagine I have two tables:

Table A

| Names | Sales | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dave | 5 | Shoes |
| mike | 6 | Apparel |
| Dan | 7 | Front End |

Table B

| Names | SALES | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dave | 5 | Shoes |
| mike | 12 | Apparel |
| Dan | 7 | Front End |
| Gregg | 23 | Shoes |
| Kim | 15 | Front End |

I want to create a query that joins the tables by names and separates sum of sales by table. I additionally want to filter my query to remove string matches or partial matches in this case by certain names.

*What I want is the following result*

Table C:

| A Sales Sum | B Sales Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | 24 |

I know I can do this with a query like the following:

```
SELECT SUM(A.sales) AS 'A Sales Sum', SUM(B.sales) AS 'B sales Sum' FROM A
JOIN B
ON B.names = A.Names
WHERE Names NOT LIKE '%Gregg%' OR NOT LIKE '%Kim%'
```

The problem with this is the WHERE clause doesn't seem to apply, or applies to the wrong table. Since the Names column doesn't exactly match between the two, what I think is happening is when they are joined 'ON B.names = A.Names', the extras from B are being excluded? When I flip things around though I get the same result, which is no filter being applied. The wrong result I am getting is the following:

Table D:

| A Sales Sum | B Sales Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | 62 |

Clearly I have a syntax issue here since I'm pretty new to SQL. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Your query would not compile as written.

Comment: You don't clearly say what rows you want to keep or remove. So we don't know what code would be correct. And if you don't clearly express yourself, how are you supposed to know? (Rhetorical.) PS [mre] [ask]

Comment: I did show an example of the query I tried to get the columns I wanted as well as a sample table containing my desired results

Comment: Like I said, "You don't clearly say". And like I said, "if you don't clearly express yourself, how are you supposed to know?" You are hoping we will guess from that example. And we cannot cut & paste & run that example.

Comment: I literally italicized "what I want is the following result" then showed the result and showed the query I was attempting to write as my best attempt clearly showing I wanted the sum of Sales for table A and B with a filter on the Names column. Again I really don't understand how I could be more specific...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a join or a union of the tables and you shouldn't do it.
Aggregate in each table separately and return the results with 2 subqueries:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT SUM(Sales) FROM A WHERE Names NOT LIKE '%Gregg%' AND Names NOT LIKE '%Kim%') ASalesSum,
  (SELECT SUM(Sales) FROM B WHERE Names NOT LIKE '%Gregg%' AND Names NOT LIKE '%Kim%') BSalesSum
```

Comment: Is there a way to use subqueries like this to add multiple rows? Like lets say I have separate tables of sales data for each department, and I wanted each row in my query to be a different labeled department, could I use the format you've given here to do something like that?

Comment: @carlb710 each subquery returns only 1 row and 1 column. If you want more than 1 rows you should use more than 1 queries like the above query combined with UNION but maybe this would not be the best way to do what you want. It's better to post a new question where you explain what you want with sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a union approach here:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN src = 'A' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS "A Sales Sum",
    SUM(CASE WHEN src = 'B' THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS "B Sales Sum"
FROM
(
    SELECT sales, 'A' AS src FROM A WHERE Names NOT IN ('Gregg', 'Kim')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sales, 'B' FROM B WHERE Names NOT IN ('Gregg', 'Kim')

) t;
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3893d53a568c91d82f340980ab58bf1b) showing that the above query is working.

Comment: Thank you for actually taking the time to read my question and give an answer before rushing to say it’s incomplete. Helpful suggestion!

Comment: would this work with partial string matches? say I was filtering out Strings that aren't names with multiple words in them. Could I just use NOT IN LIKE ('%a word%')?